# Removing suffixes with patterns in an R dataframe string variable

Tags: r, regex, function, dataframe

In my data.frame `d` below, I was wondeing how I could remove suffixes that contain any of the following:

(1) `".SHORT"` alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: `".SHORT.1"`)

(2) `".SHORT.."` followed by a number alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: `".SHORT..2.1"`)

(3) `".DEL1"` alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: `".DEL1.1"`)

(4)  `".DEL1.."` followed by a number alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: "`.DEL1..2.1`")

(5) `".DEL2"` alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: `".DEL2.1"`)

(6) `".DEL2.."` followed by a number alone or followed by a dot and any number (ex: "`.DEL2..2.1`")

```
d <- data.frame(NAMES = c("A.SHORT", "A.SHORT.2", "A.DEL1", "A.DEL1.4", "B.DEL2.4", 
"B.DEL1..2.1", "C.DEL1..2"))
```

Comment: Try `\.(?:SHORT|DEL[12])(?:\.\.(?:\d\.\d)?|\.\d)?` See https://regex101.com/r/tYoakm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(NAMES = c("A.SHORT", "A.SHORT.2", "A.DEL1",
                          "A.DEL1.4", "B.DEL2.4","B.DEL1..2.1",
                          "C.DEL1..2"))
sub("(.*)\\.(SHORT|DEL(1|2))(\\.+\\d.*)?", "\\1", d$NAMES)
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?:\.SHORT|\.DEL1|\.DEL2)(?:\.\d+|\.\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?`

This regex will match `.SHORT`, `.DEL1`, or `.DEL2`, followed optionally by a `.` and one or more digits, OR `..`, a number, and optionally `.` and another number.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKnhgd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data, we can use `substr`

```
substr(d$NAMES, 1, 1)
#[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C"
```